# How to store the text based on the tag

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to store the text based on the tag.

I have used a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewCell`.

My viewcontroller:-

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let identifier = "Cell"
        var cell: NH_QuestionListCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_QuestionListCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NH_QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_QuestionListCell
        }
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        cell.textadd = {[weak self] in

                if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {

                    print("the selected text\(cell.textname ?? "")")

                    print(i)

                    print("the Selected button is \(cell.textname ?? "")")

                    print(i)

                    cell.setText(Options:(self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))!)                     

                    let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                    print(model?.values ?? "")

                    if model?.isSelected == true{

                     cell.texttype.tag = indexPath.row
                   //  cell.texttype.text = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)

      }
      return cell

}
```

The tableviewcell:-

```
 @IBOutlet weak var texttype: UITextField!
    var textname:String?

    var textadd : ((NH_QuestionListCell) -> Void)?
    @IBAction func TextAction(_ sender: UITextField) {

         print(texttype.text)
            //    self.question.text = texttype.text

        let index = texttype.tag
        self.textname = texttype.text          

        self.textname = texttype.text
        print(self.textname)
                print(texttype.text)
             textadd?(self)
    }

    func setText(Options:NH_OptionsModel)     
    {
        self.displaySmiley.isHidden = true
        self.viewdisplay.isHidden = false
        self.imagebutton.isHidden = true
        self.question.isHidden = true
        self.displayRatingView.isHidden = true

        print(Options.values)
        Options.values = self.textname
        print(Options.values)     
    }

     func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       texttype.text = ""    
    }

    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
               return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
          self.TextAction(texttype)          
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {         
        return true;
    }      

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {           
        return true;       
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print(texttype.text)

        texttype.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }
```

I got the output. In the first cell I typed some text in the textfield and tapped "enter". Then I scrolled. At that time I found the text that I typed is available in the other cells. How to fix this problem?

Comment: how to fix the issues?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking and the code is very unorganized.

Comment: @Rigo   i have coded in this way,so now my question is firstly i enter one text in the textfield,after that at next cell i needed to type the text but here showing the text of the first cell in the 2nd cell.So while scrolling the same text is displaying in every cell.So how to fix it?

Comment: @Rigo how to fix the problem?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791041/scrollview-of-uitableview-with-multiple-textfield-shows-copy-value-from-one-to-a/49791956#49791956

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the cell `tag` since you are using a closure for each cell to handle the textfield update; This closure will capture `indexPath`, so you know which row you are updating.  The only issue that can arise is if you allow cell re-ordering, either through cell moves or the ability to insert/delete cells.  In this case the captured `indexPath` will become invalid (this is the same issue you would have with using the `tag`).  You can address this by calling `indexPath(for:)` in the closure to get the index path of the cell when the closure executes.

The reason that the text is appearing when you scroll is because cell objects are re-used and you don't explicitly set the textfield text.

Finally, you can avoid the whole `weak self` dance since when the view controller is released, the table view will be released, which means the cells will be released.  You don't have a retain cycle though the use of the closure.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let identifier = "Cell"
        var cell: NH_QuestionListCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_QuestionListCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NH_QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_QuestionListCell
        }
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.setText(options: self.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        cell.textadd = {

                self.questionViewModel.setData(atIndex: indexPath,text: cell.textName)
        }
      return cell

}
```

Note, you haven't provided details on how your model object should be updated so I have inserted a function call to show the idea.

I would also suggest that you read up on Swift conventions.  The use of capital letters for parameter names and the use of `NH_` as a class prefix is not "Swifty"

Comment: what should write in the setData?

Comment: Presumably you want to update your model with the text that the user has entered?

Comment: i have updated in the didselect method. what should do in the viewmodel